# Can't drop foreign key (using constraint name) check column/key exists

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I've tried to find a solution myself but haven't had any luck. I'm using MySQL version 8.0.14 and my problem is:

When trying to drop a foreign key...

```
alter table Employee drop foreign key fk_Employee_Contact1;
```

It fails...

```
Error Code: 1091. Can't DROP 'fk_Employee_Contact1'; check that column/key exists
```

I search for the constraint...

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
WHERE TABLE_NAME='Employee';
```

Which brings up (partial table)...

```
CONSTRAINT_NAME, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, CONSTRAINT_TYPE
'fk_Employee_Contact1', 'RRAS Test Database', 'Employee', 'FOREIGN KEY'
```

But if I search...

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE Employee;
```

It shows it as a key...

```
KEY `fk_Employee_Contact1_idx` (`idContactDets`),
```

But not as a CONSTRAINT.

I have also tried...

```
alter table Employee drop foreign key fk_Employee_Contact1_idx;
```

Which fails with the same error code. And...

```
alter table Employee drop column idContactDets;
```

Which gives...

```
Error Code: 1828. Cannot drop column 'idContactDets': needed in a foreign key constraint 'fk_Employee_Contact1'
```

Is there any way to fix this? I'm very new to databases so please explain in simple terms if possible. Thank you. :)